# CSS z-index not working (position absolute)

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am trying to make the black `div` (relative) above the second yellow one (absolute). The black `div`'s parent has a position absolute, too.

```css
#relative {
 position: relative;
 width: 40px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #000;
 z-index: 1;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.absolute {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 background: yellow;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute">
    <div id="relative"></div>
</div>
<div class="absolute" style="top: 54px"></div>
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: I wonder why my question (7y ago) is closed and marked as a duplicate of another question from 2y ago

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Remove

```
z-index:0;
```

from `.absolute`.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/P7c9q/2/)

Comment: This solved my problem as well, but… why?

Comment: @Lumen It has to do with the stacking context. As soon as you give the parent (the first `.absolute`) a z-index, the children will be inside that parent's stacking context, which is behind the second `.absolute` because it appears later. For me it helped to read [this article with visual examples](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-z-index-not-working/) and [a related, also visual StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child).

Answer (score 39):

This is because of the [Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), setting a z-index will make it apply to all children as well.

You could make the two `<div>`s siblings instead of descendants.

```
<div class="absolute"></div>
<div id="relative"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/3/

Comment: This helps me to set z-index in parents and it works. thank

Answer (score 13):

I was struggling with this problem, and I learned (thanks to [this](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) post) that:

## **opacity can also affect the z-index**

```css
div:first-child {
  opacity: .99; 
}

.red, .green, .blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.green {
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">Red</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="green">Green</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="blue">Blue</span>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here on Mozzila developers page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) you can find more details about stacking.

Answer (score 10):

I was struggling to figure it out how to put a div over an image like this:
[image: z-index working]

No matter how I configured z-index in both divs (the image wrapper) and the section I was getting this:

[image: z-index Not working]

Turns out I hadn't set up the background of the section to be `background: white;`

so basically it's like this:

```
<div class="img-wrp">
  <img src="myimage.svg"/>
</div>
<section>
 <other content>
</section>

section{
  position: relative;
  background: white; /* THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART NOT TO FORGET */
}
.img-wrp{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* also worked with 0 but just to be sure */
}
```

Comment: Thanks man you saved me for don't know how long... Thanks

Comment: @PraveenKumar happy to help!

Comment: would never in my life have guessed it was the reason

Answer (score 2):

Just add the second .absolute div before the other .second div:

```
<div class="absolute" style="top: 54px"></div>
<div class="absolute">
    <div id="relative"></div>
</div>
```

Because the two elements have an index 0.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/ks7ds/

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/4/

```
<div class="relative">
  <div class="yellow-div"></div>
  <div class="yellow-div"></div>
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>

.relative{
position:relative;
}

.absolute {
position:absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 100px;
background: #000;
z-index: 1;
top:30px;
left:0px;
}
.yellow-div {
position:relative;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background: yellow;
margin-bottom:4px;
z-index:0;
}
```

use the relative div as wrapper and let the yellow div's have normal positioning.

Only the black block need to have an absolute position then.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7W84a/)

You have to put the second div on top of the first one because the both have an z-index of zero so that the order in the dom will decide which is on top. This also affects the relative positioned div because its z-index relates to elements inside the parent div.

```
<div class="absolute" style="top: 54px"></div>
<div class="absolute">
    <div id="relative"></div>
</div>
```

Css stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my `z-index` problem by making the body wrapper `z-index:-1` and the body `z-index:-2`, and the other divs `z-index:1`.

And then the later divs didn't work unless I had `z-index` 200+. Even though I had `position:relative` on each element, with the body at default `z-index` it wouldn't work.

Hope this helps somebody.